# Unable to login to a website on wifi

Tags: networking, web

There's this website https://dev.purinamills.com/admin which works fine on wifi and 3G/4G.
But when I enter my credentials on wifi, I receive the below error:
[image]

But when I enter my credentials on my mobile using 3G data, it works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try login to the wifi homepage and try to reset the security setup. 
or check your firewall settings for blocked domains